# Possible to order by the count of an association in active record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Lets say I have `Posts` with many `Comments`

Is it possible to do an ActiveRecord query to to get the Posts ordered by most comments?

I'm surprised this relatively common query in plain old MySQL doesn't seem to have an easy answer in AR.  Yes you can use a counter_cache, but this isn't really recreating the original query.

What am I missing?

Taking it one step further.  What if `Posts` have many `Comments` which have many `Likes`.  Is it possible to get Posts with the most Likes in aggregate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, counter_cache seems to be the closest to doing it the "rails way". So far I have not encountered any AR defined methods for this specific purpose but this is the closest thing to it that I have seen:

```
@posts = Post.select("posts.*, COUNT(comments.id) AS count_comments").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id").group("posts.id").order("count_comments DESC")

@posts.each do |post|
  puts "Comments: #{post.count_comments}"
end
```

Custom select to include the count_comments attribute. Joins instead of include because include will override the select syntax. Custom joins syntax instead of merely :comments because otherwise it will be an inner join which will prevent posts without comments to be retrieved.

This is basically writing the entire SQL syntax yourself, but still... it works :)

Comment: Yep, I think that's the only solution.  All that custom SQL is really icky :)  Would be interesting if they add a cleaner way to do this to active record some day.

Comment: I don't think that, given the functionality that AREL nowadays provides, it makes sense to use raw sql for such a simple query. It looks very unelegant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do something like this as well if you want:

```
posts = Post.find(:all, :include => 'comments')
posts.sort { |a,b| b.comments.count <=> a.comments.count }
```

Comment: Doing it in ruby really only works if you have maybe 1,000 records or less in the table, so this isn't viable for tables larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

I supose you can do something like this using arel::

```
comments= Comment.arel_table
posts= Post.joins(:comments).order(comments[:id].count)
```

Though, I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. You will have to try it by yourself.